# converting jpg to .mp4 by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 320 jpg (320x574) images which I recorded with 2000 fps. I want to make a .mp4 video of them. I have run below codes in cmd (win7) and when I run the code it is working and gives me the MP4 file and I can see the video, but this attention note pops up in the cmd:

> Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it

and asked me to use other muxer or -vsync 2.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i Path/To/File/filename%d.jpg -r 2000 -pix_fmt yuv420p    path\to\result\test.mp4
```

I also tried this code with -vsync 2

```
 ffmpeg -f image2 -i Path/To/File/filename%d.jpg -r 2000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 2    path\to\result\test.mp4
```

It works, but I am not able to see the video.

First of all I wonder if the code is right to convert jpg images to MP4 video with 2000 fps?

Secondly, what should I do with the attention note?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: you realize that 320 jpg images at 2000 fps is like..1/6th of a second?

Comment: @rogerdpack yap u right, but I wounder which code is right? and I have to pay attention to the cmd's alert?